# Using Kafka and Flink for batch processing of a batch data source

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api

I am currently working on an architecture for a big data streaming and batch processing platform. I am planning on using Apache Kafka for a distributed messaging system to handle data from streaming data sources and then pass on to Apache Flink for stream processing. I would also like to use Flink's batch processing capabilities to process batch data.

Does it make sense to pass the batched data through Kafka on a periodic basis as a source for Flink batch processing (is this even possible?) or should I just write the batch data to a data store and then process by reading into Flink?